# Putting Result of Multiplication in a List

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to put a series of multiplications inside a list, I am using the code below:

```
listx = []
for i in range (2):
    list = [(3*i)]
    listx.append(list)
```

The problem is that this will put the two results inside two separate lists inside a lists, I just wants the floats to be inside the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listx = []
for i in range (2):
    listx.append(3*i)
```

Just use this one. There is no need to create another list for storing the result. You created another list to store the value and appended that list into your `listx`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehensions. Basically it's the same with for cycles but it's much shorter and for simpler operations like yours it's easier to read.

```
listx = [i*3 for i in range(2)]
```

This should produce a single list with values multiplied by 3 as integers